# How to extract numeric value from a sentence which contains specific keywords?

Tags: python, regex, text, nlp

I want to extract the numeric value from only those sentence that contains either of any word "at least", "and older", "over".

I tried writing regex but this is picking all the numeric value and I do not know put word constraint on it.

Here is the sample input:
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure you can translate this but atleast in Perl it's a simple one liner.

```perl
if($string =~ m/\b(?:at least|and older|over)\b/) { @nums = $string =~ m/(\d+)/g; }
```